# Question about Convergence in Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

We're given $Z_n $ ~ $N(0,1)$ and $ V_n $ ~ $X^2 $(n) (chi-square)

we're asked to show that $\frac{Z_n}{\sqrt{\frac{V_n}{n}}} $ $\rightarrow$ $N(0,1)$ in distribution

using Chebyshev's Theorem, We know $\frac{V_n}{n} $ $\rightarrow $ 1 in distribution, and since $\sqrt{x}$ is continuous at 1

$\sqrt{\frac{V_n}{n}}$ $\rightarrow$ 1 in distribution. Also since 1 is a constant, this also converges in probability to 1 aswell.

I'm not sure how to continue this from here. Am I suppose to apply the Central limit theorem to finish this question, or am I way off with my approach.

Comment: Apply Slutsky's theorem at the point where you stopped.

Answer (score 1):

Let $T_n=\frac  1{\sqrt {V_n/n}}$. Then $T_n \to 1$ in probability. We have to show that $Z_nT_n$ tends to standard normal distribution. Assuming independence of $(Z_n)$  and$(T_n)$ we have (by coniditioning on $T_n$)  $Ee^{iZ_nT_N}=Ee^{-t^{2}T_n^{2}/2} \to e^{-t^{2}/2}$. (At the end I used the version of DCT where almost everywhere convergence is replaced by convergence in measure).